# I'm exporting my character but the mesh keeps getting lost in export as an .fbx file why is this happening?

Tags: mesh, export, .fbx

[image: this is the export details; I had NLA deselected as I only animated using the action editor and dope sheet.]

I Really cant imagine why the mesh wont appear when I try importing the FBX into Ue5 let alone see it in 3D viewer. I checked to each pieces data properties and they all should be visible when exporting but to reiterate its simply not appearing in the file at all. Please Help.

Comment: so while I had exported the file the mesh was included in the fbx along with the intended deform bones which was exactly what i had hoped to export though im still running into the issue when importing the fbx into Ue5 it not being able to figure out the file..

Comment: when i had imported it back into blender it hadnt saved the animation data i had hoped for it to but strangely saved the last pose from the original scene and just that frame